# Embedding charts in a sheet - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So i've been trying to make a sub that makes charts off of some pivot tables in the sheet, the sheet name is "statistics". I was able to make it work a couple of times but now it doesn't work and when i debug it keeps telling me that

```
ch2016.Chart.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("A19").CurrentRegion
```

is the issue but i haven't changed anything? i don't get the problem, since it was working perfectly earlier.

```
Sub Opgave4()

Dim ch2015 As Shape
Dim ch2016 As ChartObject
Dim ch2017 As ChartObject


ActiveSheet.Select


Set ch2015 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=450, Height:=200)
Set ch2016 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=450, Top:=0, Width:=450, Height:=200)
Set ch2017 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=900, Top:=0, Width:=450, Height:=200)


ch2015.Chart.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
ch2016.Chart.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("A19").CurrentRegion
ch2017.Chart.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("G1").CurrentRegion




End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe not your issue here (might be it) but either way highly recommended - avoid using `ActiveSheet`. You mentioned that the sheet name is "Statistics", I'd replace your references to `ActiveSheet` with `Sheets("Statistics")`. Or use a `With Sheets("Statistics")...End With` construction.

Comment: _"when i debug it keeps telling me that ch2016.Chart.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("A19").CurrentRegion is the issue"_ that's not a clear description of the error.

Comment: @BigBen you were right, using Sheets("Statistics") worked :)